# Select Titles of All Books Without any Rating

Tags: sql

```
create table books
(
     id int, 
     title varchar(250), 
     year int, 
     author varchar(250)
);

create table reviewers
(
     id int, 
     name varchar(250)
);

create table ratings
(
     reviewer_id int, 
     book_id int, 
     rating int, 
     rating_date date
);
```

Select titles of all books without any rating

Now so far I have this

```
SELECT *
FROM Books
INNER JOIN Book.ID ON Reviewer.ID
WHERE Reviews.review = 'NULL'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the `Ratings` table serves as a table connecting ´Books´ and ´Reviewers´.

So to check if there are no ratings you can simply:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM books b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT book_id FROM ratings r WHERE r.book_id = b.id)
```

Meaning that this is showing all the books that do not have any rating.
PS: You don't need INNER JOINs, since you don't need any information from the rating and reviewers table (since there is none).

Answer (score 0):

The way your question is phrased, think "not exists":  You want books where a review does not exist:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM Books b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Ratings r WHERE r.BookId = b.id);
```